# Orchard cms apicontroller that returns xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, orchardcms

I've been trying to implement David Hayden's Orchard CMS and ASP .NET Web API http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/orchard-cms-and-asp.net-web-api, but I'm running into problems, basically getting a page not found.

This is what I have:

Under my controllers

ContactViewModel.cs

```
namespace Sunkist.ContactManager.Controllers
{
 public class ContactsController : ApiController
 {
    private readonly IContentManager _contentManager;

    public ContactsController(IContentManager contentManager)
    {
        _contentManager = contentManager;
    }

    public IEnumerable<ContactViewModel> Get()
    {
        return _contentManager
            .Query(VersionOptions.Published, "Contact")
            .List()
            .Select(c => new ContactViewModel(c));
    }

    public ContactViewModel Get(int id)
    {
        var contact = _contentManager.Get(id);

        if (contact == null)
            throw new HttpResponseException
              (new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));

        return new ContactViewModel(contact);
    }
 }
}
```

ViewModel folder
ViewModel.cs

```
namespace Sunkist.ContactManager.ViewModel
{
  public class ContactViewModel
  {
    private Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem c;

    public ContactViewModel(Orchard.ContentManagement.ContentItem c)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.c = c;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
  }
}
```

and migration

```
namespace Sunkist.ContactManager {
  public class Migrations : DataMigrationImpl {

    public int Create() {
        // Creating table ContactRecord
        SchemaBuilder.CreateTable("ContactRecord", table => table
            .ContentPartRecord()
            .Column("Name", DbType.String)
            .Column("Address", DbType.String)
            .Column("City", DbType.String)
        );

        return 1;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm new to both Orchard and .Net MVC, So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You get a 404 when you go where?

Comment: when I try to hit the page: http://localhost:30321/OrchardLocal/api/sunkist.contactmanager/contacts

Comment: Are you sure this is the correct url for your action? Did you create a custom route? Where does the "api" part come from? According to the article you linked, it should be /api/contacts, if you created that route.

Comment: I'm trying to implement an ApiController as well.  I get a 404 just trying to hit my Orchard root page.  When i exclude my equivelent of ContactsController.cs and recompile the module, the Orchard root page loads just fine.  Is Orchard behaving the same way for you?  Or just when you try to hit your /api/sunkist... page?

Answer (score 0):

Double check the name of the module that contains the Web API controller.

Via VS GUI, I created a new web api controller class "TestController.cs" and could not find the correct endpoint url.

That is, until I looked at the Module.txt in the project I added the controller to.  The project is "Orchard.Users", but the name in the Module.txt file is just "Users".

I was able to hit the endpoint at "http://example.com/api/users/test".

Noteworthy: I setup a route for this at ".../UsersApi", but the 'auto-magic' URL pattern still works. Code below. Also, I later added a new module to contain my api controller and it would not work until I enabled the module in the dashboard.

**TestController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace Orchard.Users.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/<controller>/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/<controller>
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/<controller>/5
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/<controller>/5
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**HttpRoutes.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Orchard.Mvc.Routes;
using Orchard.WebApi.Routes;

public class HttpRoutes : IHttpRouteProvider
{

    public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes)
    {
        foreach (RouteDescriptor routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
        {
            routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes()
    {
        return new[] {
                new HttpRouteDescriptor {
                    Name = "UsersApi",
                    Priority = -10,
                    RouteTemplate = "usersapi/{id}",
                    Defaults = new { 
                        area = "Orchard.Users", 
                        controller = "Test",
                        id = RouteParameter.Optional
                    },
                }
            };
        }
    }
```